# Rest API param in particular format

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I have to call a rest api in asp.net webforms (c#)
https://connect.mycomp.in/ConnectTP/PlaceOrder

```
Below is the curl example
curl \
-X POST https://BaseURL/PlaceOrder \
-d "jData={\"uid\":\"Test\", \"actid\":\"Test\", 
\"qty\":\"50\", \"price\":\"1400\", \"ret\":\"DAY\"}“ \
-d “jKey=TRELIU34533456SSUDFGU234”
```

I am trying with JavaScriptSerializer but it is not working as expected, any help is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance

```
     object input = new jData
                {
                    uid = "xxxxxxx",
                    actid = "xxxxxxx",
                    ..........,
                    ..........,
                 },jKey = "KEYHERe";
  string inputJson = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(input);
```

-----------------Update----------------------------------------

server returned bad request for this call, can someone guide

```
var jd1 = new jData
        {
            uid = "xxxxxxx",
            actid = "xxxxxxx",
            ................,
            ..........,

        };

        object input = new PlaceOrderParam
        {
            jData = jd1,
            jKey = Session["tk"].ToString()
        };

        string inputJson = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(input);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
        client.Encoding = Encoding.Default;
        string json = client.UploadString(apiUrl, inputJson);
```

Update 2------------------------------------------------------

```
 using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), apiUrl))
                {
                    request.Content = new StringContent("jData={\"uid\":\"xxxxxxx\",\"actid\":\"xxxxxxx\",\"ret\":\"DAY\"}\" , \"jKey=" + Session["tk"].ToString() + "");
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

                    var response =  await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                }
            }
```

Tried converting the curl to HttpClient but still it's a bad request

Update 3--------------------------

```
QUERY PARAMETERS
Parameter
Name    Possible value  Description
jData*      Should send json object with fields in below list
jKey*       Key Obtained on login success.
```

Comment: Please describe the sentence "it is not working as expected" more detailed, You should specify your code which is not working

Comment: @RaminRahimzada added the code, actually the input string is not as expected, so looking help in correcting the format. Thanks

Comment: You still haven't really described your problem.  It's not clear what format you are getting vs the format you are expecting.

Comment: May be I am not clear, I want to call the rest service and the document given has sample curl command for the same. Based on the curl command I am trying to call the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use two `-d` parameters for `curl`. If you do, only the last one will be passed, which means your payload is `jKey=TRELIU34533456SSUDFGU234`, which is probably not what you intended. Furthermore, that's not even valid JSON, which is what `JavaScriptSerializer.serialize()` outputs.

I think your `curl` command should look like

```
curl \
-X POST https://BaseURL/PlaceOrder \
-H "application/json" \
-d "{\"jData\":{\"uid\":\"Test\", \"actid\":\"Test\", \"qty\":\"50\", \"price\":\"1400\",\"ret\":\"DAY\"}, \"jKey\":\"TRELIU34533456SSUDFGU234\"}"
```

Your JavaScript looks correct, so not sure why that's not working.

It's a bit hard to say for either the `curl` call or the JavaScript without knowing what the API is expecting.

It looks like the line continuations (`\`) and odd quotes (`“` and `”`) vs (`"`) might be tripping you up as well. (I may be off on that--might be a copy/paste thing into your question). I edited the command to remove the line continuations from possibly messing up the JSON string hase to escape the quotes.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Actually the vendor has given the curl command, also I am not trying to execute curl command, trying to call though HttpClient but it is always returning "Bad Request". Please check the question for update

Comment: The documentation doesn't make sense. Why would a POST use query parameters and not content in the body? The error message is saying you need the `jData` and the `jKey` as query parameters and not content. Their `curl` example doesn't match what it is doing... seems like their API/example/actual implementation are conflicting.